# How to create a dataset similar to PeMsD8?

Tags: python, dataset

Currently, I have obtained traffic data and site data from PeMs.However, as I have just come into contact with this thing, I am not sure how to make it, nor have I found any relevant tutorials.

I once found an article on csdn describing this, but the distance generated according to his description is not in the form of a adjacency matrix. I cannot run it on STFGNN, it always leads to various errors such as boundary overflow.